# using azure data factory to retrieve blobs urls from a container

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure, I have some blobs in a container, what I'm looking for is to copy the urls of these blobs in a json file using azure data factory or data flow.

heres as example of a url :

[image]

the expected result is :

> [[{'ur':'urltObLOB1'},{'ur':'urltObLOB2'},{'ur':'urltObLOB3'},.....]

is there a way to achieve that using azure data factory or data flow please ?

Comment: Using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do to people you want to help you. Please edit your question title and body to use normal capitalization.

Comment: Please stop using ALL CAPS - it's widely considered to be equivalent to shouting. Please edit your question to use normal capitalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an activity or out of the box method to achieve the ask. However if you look at the REST api

[The List Blobs operation returns a list of the blobs under the specified container.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs)

> In version 2013-08-15 and newer, the EnumerationResults element
> contains a ServiceEndpoint attribute specifying the blob endpoint, and
> a ContainerName field specifying the name of the container. In
> previous versions these two attributes were combined together in the
> ContainerName field. Also in version 2013-08-15 and newer, the Url
> element under Blob has been removed.

Checkout MS DOC [List blobs and snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enumerating-blob-resources#list-blobs-and-snapshots)

An example shows the result of a listing operation that returns blobs and snapshots in a container named `mycontainer`.

The request URI is as follows:

```
GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list&include=snapshots&include=metadata
```

Sample XML response contains a block for each blob in the container.

```
   <Blob>  
      <Name>blob3.txt</Name>  
      <Url>https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/blob3.txt</Url>  
      <Properties>  
        <Last-Modified>Wed, 09 Sep 2009 09:20:03 GMT</Last-Modified>  
        <Etag>0x8CBFF45D911FADF</Etag>  
        <Content-Length>16384</Content-Length>  
        <Content-Type>image/jpeg</Content-Type>  
        <Content-Encoding />  
        <Content-Language />  
        <Content-MD5 />  
        <Cache-Control />  
        <x-ms-blob-sequence-number>3</x-ms-blob-sequence-number>  
        <BlobType>PageBlob</BlobType>  
        <LeaseStatus>locked</LeaseStatus>  
      </Properties>  
      <Metadata>  
        <Color>yellow</Color>  
        <BlobNumber>03</BlobNumber>  
        <SomeMetadataName>SomeMetadataValue</SomeMetadataName>  
      </Metadata>  
    </Blob>
```

You can find the blob URL between `<Url> </Url>`

Next you can parse the XML output to store the `url` values in an array variable in the pipeline.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so I can use web activity to call GET Endpoint, and then retrieve the list and put them in a file, what do you think ?

Comment: that is correct. Once you get the XML response, you can use a Dataflow activity to parse and get an array or just file name and URL like you expect